# How to append the datetime to the file name which publish to Azure Data Lake Store by Data factory?

Tags: azure

I try to use the Azure Data Factory to push the data from table storage to Azure Data Lake Store. And in Data Factory.

I defined the output entity and try to add the `datetime` to the output file, but seems it doesn't work.

See the code below:

```
 *"published": false,
        "type": "AzureDataLakeStore",
        "linkedServiceName": "Destination-DataLakeStore-bwb",
        "typeProperties": {
            "fileName": "tbTotalTollData{year}{Month}{Day}{Hour}",
            "folderPath": "Samples",
            "format": {
                "type": "TextFormat",
                "columnDelimiter": ","
            }
        }
```

Use the `{year}{Month}{Day}{Hour}` for the file name, but not work.

Answer (score 0):

The variables year, Month, Day that are used in the above code should be declared. Update the code as follows and try again                                   `*"published": false,
        "type": "AzureDataLakeStore",
        "linkedServiceName": "Destination-DataLakeStore-bwb",
        "typeProperties": {
            "fileName": "tbTotalTollData{year}{Month}{Day}{Hour}",
            "folderPath": "Samples",
            "format": {
                "type": "TextFormat",
                "columnDelimiter": ","
            }
        },
        "partitionedBy": [
                {
                    "name": "Year",
                    "value": {
                        "type": "DateTime",
                        "date": "SliceStart",
                        "format": "yyyy"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Month",
                    "value": {
                        "type": "DateTime",
                        "date": "SliceStart",
                        "format": "MM"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Day",
                    "value": {
                        "type": "DateTime",
                        "date": "SliceStart",
                        "format": "dd"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Hour",
                    "value": {
                        "type": "DateTime",
                        "date": "SliceStart",
                        "format": "hh"
                    }
                }
            ]`

Answer (score 0):

I have a Azure Data Factory "Copy Data" pipeline that backs up CosmosDb collections into a blob storage account based on guidance from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/online-backup-and-restore

I wanted to include the timestamp information in the file name and achieved it by adding this:

@concat(formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'), '_', item().destination.fileName)

**Results:**  20190212161116_Products.txt

[image]